# Select items of kendo-combobox from other controls

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-combobox

I have a `kendo-combobox`. [Keyboard navigation works very well](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/keyboard-navigation/) when focus is at `kendo-combobox`.

ButI would like to select next available item through the buttons which placed near the `kendo-combobox`. Let me show my code:

HTML:

```
<p>Favorite sport:</p>  
<kendo-combobox [data]="listItems" [allowCustom]="true" #superComboBox>
</kendo-combobox>

<button (click)="selectUpperItem()">
    Up
</button>
<button (click)="selectLowerItem()">
    Down
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
public listItems: Array<string> = 
[
   "Baseball", "Basketball", "Cricket", "Field Hockey", "Football", "Table Tennis", 
   "Tennis", "Volleyball"
];

selectUpperItem(){
   //pseudocode: this.superComboBox.nextUpperItem();    
   //How can I accomplish this?
}

selectLowerItem(){
   //pseudocode: this.superComboBox.nextLowerItem();    
   //How can I accomplish this?
}
```

Controls looks like this:

[image]

So, for example,  when I click at the `Up` button, then the next available item should be selected at the `kendo-combobox`.

Is it possible to select next available item through the buttons which placed near the `kendo-combobox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to select options with the Up/Down buttons you can do something like the following.

Use `[(ngModel)]` to track current selection:

```
<kendo-combobox 
    [data]="listItems" 
    [allowCustom]="allowCustom" 
    [(ngModel)]="currentSelection">
</kendo-combobox>
```

Then in your `.ts` check if `currentSelection` is `undefined` and manipulate the selection/index accordingly:

```
private string: currentSelection;
private number: currentIndex;

private selectUpperItem() {
  if (this.currentSelection == undefined) {
    this.currentSelection = this.listItems[this.listItems.length - 1];
    this.currentIndex = this.listItems.length - 1;
  } else {
    this.currentIndex = this.listItems.indexOf(this.currentSelection);
    this.currentSelection = this.listItems[this.currentIndex - 1];
  }
}

private selectLowerItem() {
  if (this.currentSelection == undefined) {
    this.currentSelection = this.listItems[0];
    this.currentIndex = 0;
  } else {
    this.currentIndex = this.listItems.indexOf(this.currentSelection);
    this.currentSelection = this.listItems[this.currentIndex + 1];
  }
}
```

It is set so if `undefined` and click Up will choose last option and when `undefined` and Down is clicked will choose first option.

Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/Yp7dXC5o6bLPaKVELc74).